# finite steps to Hessenberg form and/or triangular form

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, computational-mathematics

I am learning numerical linear algebra and curious about one thing. It is possible to reduce any matrix to the Hessenberg form in finite steps with a unitary matrix. But why is it impossible to reduce it further into an upper triangular form in finite step?

What is the fundamental barrier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could reduce to a triangular matrix $A = QTQ^*$ (a [Schur factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition)) in a finite number of steps (involving elementary arithmetic operations and n-th roots only), this would violate the [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem): it would allow you to exactly (neglecting roundoff errors) compute roots of arbitrary polynomials in a finite number of steps.

The reason is that the diagonal entries of the triangular matrix $T$ are equal to the eigenvalues of $A$, and for any degree-$n$ polynomial $p(z)$ you can find the roots by transforming $p$ into a corresponding $n \times n$ matrix (a [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix)).

The Abel–Ruffini theorem says that it is impossible to find the roots of an arbitrary polynomial of degree 5 or higher in a finite number of elementary steps (there is no "quintic formula").  That tells us that it is impossible to find the Schur factorization of an arbitrary matrix (exactly) in a finite number of steps for matrices $5 \times 5$ or larger.   Hence, all Schur algorithms (unlike Hessenberg reductions) are approximate "iterative" algorithms that *approach* the factor $T$ but never exactly reach it (but in practice can quickly approximate $T$ to any desired precision).

(Proving the Abel–Ruffini theorem is nontrivial!  It was one of the great triumphs of 19th-century mathematics, resolving a question that had puzzled mathematicians for 2000 years.)